# How do I build and run specific files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, vscode-liveshare

I am writing a program with some mates and we are using live share to all work on the same code. Something we want to do is make a .cpp file to test the header (.h) and their associated (.cpp) file without building and running all of the files. If it is not possible we will just copy the code over into another project and run it separately for testing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, you can choose which projects in a solution build, this is done by checking/unchecking boxes in the Build tab->Configuration manager. If you can't separate the files into separate projects, you can exclude files from build in the proj file, check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-exclude-files-from-the-build?view=vs-2019